# Can I allocate this string statically? How?

Tags: c, arrays, string, malloc

I've never been sure about the correct way of doing this.
I'm trying to write the following function

```
int obtain_substr(int seqn, char *fullstring, int position, char **ret_string);
```

I want it to get a substring of defined `STRSIZE` from the `position`th `char` of `fullstring`, prepending `seqn` to the output string (that will be `*ret_string`).

So, for example, if I have the following values:

```
#define STRSIZE 7
seqn = 2;
fullstring = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet."
position = 3;
```

I want `obtain_substr` to return the following value:

```
*ret_string = "2em ipsu";
```

What I've been doing until now is the following function, but I'm honestly not sure about its implementation:

```
int obtain_substr(int seqn, char *fullstring, int position, char **ret_string) {
    char *buf = malloc(sizeof(char) * STRSIZE);
    memset((void *) buf, 0, sizeof(char) * STRSIZE);
    if (buf == NULL) {
        perror("malloc");
        return -1;
    }
    buf = strncpy(buf, fullstring + position, STRSIZE); // Obtain substring
    sprintf(*ret_string, "%d%s", seqn, buf); // Merge sequence number and substring
    return 0;
}
```

Am I forgetting to manage some `\0` ending the strings? Since I know exactly the size of the output string, can I declare it statically? If yes, how am I supposed to edit my code? I'm thinking using `malloc` and `memset` every time, knowing the substring will be exactly of size `STRSIZE + 1` (maybe `+2` for the `\0`?) may be suboptimal.

Comment: @coderredoc with an array instead of using `malloc` (e.g. `char buf[STRSIZE + 1]`)

Comment: Is there a reason you have the caller doing the allocating for the return string? It seems unnecessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Malloc vs plain array

Yes, you can use array with automatic storage duration. If you declare it with `static`it won't be placed in stack in most implementations. But with `STRSIZE` being so small, I'd say stack overflow is unlikely.

You can also use initializer to avoid `memset`.

```
int obtain_substr(int seqn, char *fullstring, int position, char **ret_string) {
    char buf[STRSIZE + 1] = {0}; // +1 for \0
    strncpy(buf, fullstring + position, STRSIZE);
    sprintf(*ret_string, "%d%s", seqn, buf);
    return 0;
}
```

### Strncpy is garbage

`strncpy` won't null terminate string correctly if string is exactly `STRSIZE` in size. You have to terminate string manually to be sure.

```
int obtain_substr(int seqn, char *fullstring, int position, char **ret_string) {
    char buf[STRSIZE + 1] = {0}; // +1 for \0
    strncpy(buf, fullstring + position, STRSIZE);
    buf[STRSIZE] = 0;
    sprintf(*ret_string, "%d%s", seqn, buf);
    return 0;
}
```

Strictly speaking this is not necessary, since we initialize `buf` to all zeros, and last element is not modified by `strncpy`. But this kind of thing can easily be broken when editing function. It doesn't hurt to be explicit about it.

### Improvements

You don't actually need temporary buffer: You can limit the size of copied string with `snprintf` precision parameter, which with `%s` is max limit.

Every string function that edits string, should receive also size of available space to avoid overflows. (You should use `snprintf` over `sprintf` when you can.)  There also seems to be no reason for ret_string to be double pointer.

`fullstring` should also be declared `const` as it's not modified by this function.

```
int obtain_substr(int seqn, char const *fullstring, size_t position, char *ret_string, size_t ret_size) {
    snprintf(ret_string, ret_size, "%d%.*s", seqn, STRSIZE, fullstring + position);
    return 0;
}
```

You would call this like:

```
#define SIZE 16
char str[SIZE];
obtain_substr(2, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.", 3, str, SIZE);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, very clarifying! How should I call your function at last? (I mean, how should I initialize `ret_string` and `ret_size`?)

Comment: @Robb1 Added small example.

Answer (score 0):

Change `seqn` from `int` to `char*`, then you could change the prototype from

```
int obtain_substr(int seqn, char *fullstring, int position, char **ret_string);
```

to

```
char* obtain_substr(char* seqn, char *fullstring, int position);
```

Then do something like

```
// At this point, you know the length of the target string.
size_t seql=strlen(seqn);
int l=seql+STRSIZE,j,i;
char* ret_string=malloc((l+1)* sizeof *ret_string);
//+1 for the null character
if(NULL == ret_string)
  exit(1); // Can't allocate memory

for(i=0;i<seql;i++)
      ret_string[i]=seqn[i]; // Reads the sequence

for(i=seql,j=position;i<l;i++)
      ret_string[i]=fullstring[j++] // Reads specified number of chars

ret_string[j]='\0'; // Important ! null terminate the string
return ret_string;
```